# Are Pokemon that spawn after a space-time distortion completely new ones?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

I was approaching a space-time distortion, and was wasting some time waiting for it to start. When suddenly I heard the "sparkle" sound of a shiny Pokemon. That was so unexpected, also because a couple of seconds later the distortion began and every wild Pokemon vanished.

According to Serebii, when a [space-time distortion](https://www.serebii.net/legendsarceus/space-timedistortions.shtml) is formed:

> The Pokémon in it will change and it'll start spawning rare items.

But what about those who appear after it has ended? Are the Pokemon that spawn after the distortion brand new ones, or are they the same you had 4 minutes before?

Because I feel I lost a shiny without even seeing it. I searched everywhere but no shiny was there.

Comment: Hmm, not sure we'll have a better answer than your own evidence here (that they are probably new).  I suspect they are - but since the spawns in any area are so consistent it's hard to prove it... sorry about losing the shiny though!  I haven't seen one since my two psyducks early on myself, so I'd be pretty salty if this happened to me!

Comment: @Joe I had the same impression, unfortunately. Thanks for the sympathy :) at least the odds are not so bad in this game, I'll find another one. The bad thing is that I was in a Gastly area, and I really wanted a shiny one.

Comment: @pinckerman You aren't alone. This happened to a friend of mine. RIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a space-time distortion manifests, all wild Pokémon within the area of effect (except Unown) are despawned, and items that normally cannot be found in the overworld will appear, including shards, evolution items, and various valuable items. It's a soft reset, you can check about the mechanic more on this [link](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Space-time_distortion)